# Derivative of ReLU in NN

Tags: math, neural-network

Assuming there is a two layer network

```
Input (N*D matrix) -> W1 (D*H matrix) -> ReLU -> W2 (H*C matrix) 
-> Output (N*C matrix)
```

When I was trying to calculate the derivative in backpropagation. In my opinion, the derivative of W2 should be a H*C matrix. And then I calculate the local derivative of ReLU, which should be a N*H matrix (same as the input of ReLU). And the final derivative of ReLU should be N*H * H*C = N*C matrix (chain rule). But I think the result is not right. I think it should be N*H matrix. Could you tell me the right way to backpropagate through ReLU? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReLU forward is 0 if x < 0 and x otherwise.

Derivative of this is: 0 if x < 0 and 1 otherwise.

That means that during backpropagation you leave positive values unchanged and multiply negative by 0. The shape of matrix is unchanged.

Comment: Yeah. I know that. Assumes the input is a N*H matrix, and the local gradient of ReLU is a N*H matrix too. So during the backpropagation, should I multiply the previous gradient matrix with this local gradient directly? Thanks

Comment: Almost. You multiply local gradient with the input in locations where the input values are positive.

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko Is that mean that ReLU does kill the neurons during both forward and backward pass processes?